# Alps Loaded but PS/2 mouse also loaded!

Tags: dell, touchpad, inspiron, alps

i have Dell Inspiron 15R and i installed `psmouse-alps` package, it successfully recognized my Touchpad and i can see touchpad option under mouse properties as well, but my touchpad doesn't works at all. Here is the output of `xinput --list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer            id=4    [slave  pointer (2)] 
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Mouse                            id=14   [slave pointer  (2)] 
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint              id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)] 
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard           id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                          id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                             id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                             id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                          id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                      id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: If someone needs Xorg.o.log i can provide as well!

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same problem on my Inspiron N5110 running Ubuntu 12.04 but was able to fix it using patch and instructions provided in these two links.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/606238/comments/144

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/606238/comments/147

Touchpad is now recognised as a AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad and Touchpad tab is enabled in System Settings. Unfortunately, scrolling is still not an option... :-(

At least touchpad is disabled while typing, which was the biggest problem for me resulting in cryptic writings! :-)

[EDIT]: Also Fn+F3 is working now (aka, touchpad toggle).

Comment: Is this really the same problem you experienced? I ask because you seem to have posted this as an answer to multiple questions, and the problem here is *not* that the touchpad isn't recognized, but that the driver for another device is *also* loaded, and that driver is the one that is active. *You might want to edit this answer to make it more specific to this question.*

Comment: I must admit I've copy-pasted this answer to several threads regarding Alps touchpad. On some of them this isn't the real answer to the question that was asked, but this is really exactly the same problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to my own [post](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=121946), this is the solution that I found after reading many forums. I use a Dell Inspiron 14R, and now the touchpad is detected & gestures are working.
Save the following in a .sh file, make it executable, and just run.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /usr/src/
sudo wget http://www.dahetral.com/public-download/psmouse-alps-dst-1.2.tbz
sudo tar jxvf ./psmouse-alps-dst-1.2.tbz -C /
cd /usr/src/psmouse-alps-dst-1.2
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms build -m psmouse -v alps-dst-1.2
sudo dkms install -m psmouse -v alps-dst-1.2
sudo modprobe psmouse
echo -n "Installation complete"
read text
```