# Alps Touchpad driver loaded, but still touchpad not working?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, alps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alps Loaded but PS/2 mouse also loaded!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109820/alps-loaded-but-ps-2-mouse-also-loaded)

I have a Dell Inspiron 15R with Ubuntu 11.10 x86-64 installed. I am having a problem with the Alps touchpad. My touchpad's driver loads, which is `synaptics`, and it gets recognized in `xinput --list` and in `Xorg.0.log`, but it's still not working. In `xinput --list` I can see two devices loaded at the same bus: "PS/2 Mouse" and "Alps/PS2 ALPS GlidePoint".

Any workaround and any further logs will be provided (if) when requested.

Comment: The touchpad support was improved recent kernels, so switching to a newer kernel could help.

Comment: installed kernel 3.3.0 rc5, but still that problem persists, everything is loaded, i mean every driver!

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same problem on my Inspiron N5110 running Ubuntu 12.04 but was able to fix it using patch and instructions provided in these two links.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/606238/comments/144

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/606238/comments/147

Touchpad is now recognised as a AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad and Touchpad tab is enabled in System Settings. Unfortunately, scrolling is still not an option... :-(

At least touchpad is disabled while typing, which was the biggest problem for me resulting in cryptic writings! :-)

[EDIT]: Also Fn+F3 is working now (aka, touchpad toggle).