# Alps touchpad under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS not working

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, dell, alps

**The essential**

I have a Dell Precision 6600, with an Alps touchpad under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
The touchpad does not work at all, but it used to work fine, with two-finger scrolling, etc.

*Symptoms*:

1. The touchpad does not work at all. 
   Touchpad buttons work. 
   An external mouse works. 
   The [pointing stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointing_stick) works.
2. The touchpad is detected, see below the output of `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`, `xinput --list`, `xinput --list-props 12`.
3. `touchpad-indicator` does not see the touchpad (and exits with error). This is perhaps ok (though I am not sure), since I have an Alps, and it might be ok not to have a synaptics driver.
   See below the output of `touchpad-indicator`.
4. In System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad, there is a single tab (some -[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248290/enable-both-edge-scrolling-and-two-finger-scrolling-for-touchpad/248304#248304) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469667/mouse-and-touchpad-settings-missing)- see a separate tab for the touchpad) with no settings for the touchpad.
5. There is no touchpad in `gconf-editor` -> desktop -> gnome -> peripherals (I do see mouse and keyboard). 
   See below what I got when looking for related settings.
   I do not know where to check more on this to gather additional relevant info.

I do not know when the touchpad stopped working.
The only thing I recall as a possibility is when I issued

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

As far as I recall, I did this when trying to make Virtualbox work.

Any hints on how to recover the touchpad?

---

**What else I found**

1. I have found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623598/dell-inspiron-7347-inactive-cursor-with-my-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04), but prior to trying this option I would like to check if i8042 and i2c-hid are potential issues in my case.
2. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109820/alps-loaded-but-ps-2-mouse-also-loaded) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154770/alps-touchpad-on-dell-how-do-i-install-the-dkms-driver-to-enable-multitouch/278133#278133) seem to apply to 12.04. Further, kernel support for touchpad seems to have evolved a lot, so old posts like [this](http://linuxsagas.digitaleagle.net/2013/10/14/ubuntu-13-04-finally-fixing-my-touchpad/), [this](http://linuxg.net/ubuntu-13-04-touchpad-option-does-not-exist-error-fix/), and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368940/dell-alps-touchpad-not-working) are likely outdated.
3. `evtest` detects touchpad activity when [debugging](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection/evtest). See also [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection).
4. I am not sure if [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505633/alps-touchpad-detected-as-ps-2-corrected-with-psmouse-dkms-alpsv7-but-reset-aft) and [this](https://nwoki.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/multitouch-fix-for-alps-touchpad/) refer to recovering multitouch, not to getting back functionality from nothing.

---

**Output of various commands.**

devices:

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
...
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0008 Version=0300
N: Name="AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event6
B: PROP=8
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e420 70000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800001000003
...
```

xinput:

```
$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DualPoint Stick                           id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ OM                                        id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_FHD              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

xinput --list-props:

```
$ xinput --list-props 12
Device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad':
        Device Enabled (141):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (143): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        Device Accel Profile (269):     0
        Device Accel Constant Deceleration (270):       1.000000
        Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (271):       1.000000
        Device Accel Velocity Scaling (272):    10.000000
        Device Product ID (260):        2, 8
        Device Node (261):      "/dev/input/event6"
        Evdev Axis Inversion (273):     0, 0
        Evdev Axis Calibration (274):   <no items>
        Evdev Axes Swap (275):  0
        Axis Labels (276):      "Abs MT Position X" (267), "Abs MT Position Y" (268), "Abs Pressure" (266), "None" (0), "None" (0)
        Button Labels (277):    "Button Left" (144), "Button Middle" (145), "Button Right" (146), "Button Wheel Up" (147), "Button Wheel Down" (148)
        Evdev Middle Button Emulation (278):    0
        Evdev Middle Button Timeout (279):      50
        Evdev Third Button Emulation (280):     0
        Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (281):     1000
        Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (282):      3
        Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (283):   20
        Evdev Wheel Emulation (284):    0
        Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (285):       0, 0, 4, 5
        Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (286):    10
        Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (287):    200
        Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (288):     4
        Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (289):  0
```

touchpad-indicator:

```
$ /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/touchpad-indicator/bin/touchpad-indicator &> touchpad-indicator.txt
$ cat touchpad-indicator.txt 
No LSB modules are available.
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
<gettext.GNUTranslations object at 0x7f4ec797a550>
#####################################################
#####################################################
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
Version:        x86_64
#####################################################

Touchpad-Indicator version: 1.1.0-0extras15.04.3-src
#####################################################
pidof syndaemon
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/touchpad-indicator/bin/touchpad-indicator", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/touchpad-indicator/share/touchpad-indicator/touchpad_indicator.py", line 495, in main
    tpi=TouchpadIndicator()
  File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/touchpad-indicator/share/touchpad-indicator/touchpad_indicator.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.read_preferences()
  File "/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/touchpad-indicator/share/touchpad-indicator/touchpad_indicator.py", line 274, in read_preferences
    self.synclient.set('VertScrollDelta',abs(int(self.synclient.get('VertScrollDelta'))))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
Exception ignored in: <bound method Context.__del__ of <pyudev.core.Context object at 0x7f4ec74cfa58>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyudev/core.py", line 98, in __del__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'udev_unref'
```

Others

```
$ locate /desktop/gnome/peripherals
(empty output)
$ locate /desktop/gnome/ | grep mouse
(empty output)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had rebooted a few times prior to posting the OP, and the touchpad did not work at all.
Now it works, and I did nothing (as far as I can tell) in-between. No `apt-get dist-upgrade`, etc.